# "similitude method" for the case: $\nu''-2\nu'+\nu= \frac {e^x}{x}$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

As title says...

I have already tried things like $\nu(x)=\log(x^{\lambda})e^x$

or $\nu(x)=\dfrac{e^x \lambda}{x}$

But with no success, stinks of logarithms but I don't know...

Comment: Why not to try directly $\nu(x)=e^xy(x)$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y''-2y'+y= \frac {e^x} x$$

$$y''-y'-(y'-y)= \frac {e^x} x$$
Substitute $h=y'-y$
$$h'-h=\frac {e^x} x$$

Which is a first ODe easy to solve

$$ {e^{-x}h'-e^{-x}h}=\frac {1} x$$

$$ {h}{e^{-x}}=\int \frac {dx} x$$

$$ h=y'-y= {e^{x}}(\ln(x)+K)$$

$$ e^{-x}y'-ye^{-x}= \ln(x)+K$$

$$ (ye^{-x})'= \ln(x)+K$$

$$ y=e^{x} \int(\ln(x)+K )dx$$

$$ y=e^{x}(x\ln(x)+K_1x+K_2)$$

Answer (score 4):

With $\nu(x)=e^x y(x)$, the LHS of the equation keeps an exp. factor, which should simplify the ode. We have directly
$$e^x\frac{d^2}{dx^2}y(x)=\frac{e^x}x$$
Then $$y(x)=x\ln x+ax+b$$
where $a$ and $b$ are arbritrary constants.
$$\nu(x)=\left(x\ln x+ax+b\right)e^x$$